# Application crashes with CastCompanionLibrary

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

For some reason, as soon as I add the CastCompanionLibrary to my project, it crashes with this error:

`04-22 11:58:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(3258): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.test: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=com.test id=347 tag=null notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x62))`

I'm running this on an HTC Incredible on Android 2.3.4.

Please help!

Comment: I just removed all this code and the error is still there. It happens just by adding the Cast Companion Library to my project. Any ideas why that would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by renaming my custom_notification.xml file and also updating the id of the layout inside. I think it had a conflict with the custom_notification.xml from the CCL.